# Getting Uploadify to stick to a server behind a AWS load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, uploadify

basic question is how do I get uploadify to stick to a server behind a load balancer. I have 2 AWS servers behind a LB, and am trying to upload files to a S3. 
I'm using basic code seen elsewhere and this works intermittently. I can dump out the server address and see that , on occasion, the JavaScript that calls a server, gets routed to the OTHER server.

```
$('#video_file_upload').uploadify({
        'buttonText':'upload a video',
        'swf'      : '/uploads/uploadify.swf',
        'fileSizeLimit': '1000MB',
        'uploader' : '/assets/receive/?PSPSESSIONID=XXXXXX&type=video',

...etc
```

So, you see, the java script is trying to access a php script at "/assets/receive...", but it gets confused as to which server the script is on.
So the question is, how to make this request sticky? 
I have sticky sessions set up , but It doesnt seem like it applies here.

Comment: Do you have elb sticky sessions or are you using an application generated cookie?

Comment: Elb Sticky sessions are on